# Type error using lodash to create a unique array from an array of objects

Tags: arrays, typescript, unique, lodash

The error I'm getting is `'LoDashExplicitWrapper<string[]>' is not assignable to type 'string[]'. Property 'length' is missing in type 'LoDashExplicitWrapper<string[]>'.` using **lodash v4.17.10**

I have an array of objects, and I'm trying to get an array that has only the unique values of a property on each object.

The code:

```
let carMakes: string[]
const inventory = [
  { make: "ford", model: "Focus" },
  { make: "ford", model: "F-150" },
  { make: "chevy", model: "Camaro" }

carMakes = _.chain(inventory)
            .map('make')
            .uniq()
```

Is there any way I can make this work with chaining, as that makes for what appears like a nice clean solution, although it's not working (here in my Angular project)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a plain js Set and `map()` the data once. By directly reconverting it to an array using `Array.from()` you get the desired `string[]`.

```js
const inventory = [{
    make: "ford",
    model: "Focus"
  },
  {
    make: "ford",
    model: "F-150"
  },
  {
    make: "chevy",
    model: "Camaro"
  }
];

const unique =  Array.from(new Set(inventory.map(({make}) => make)));
console.log(unique);
```

Comment: Ooo, forgot about Sets, as I haven't used them before now. However, I now get this new error: `[ts] Type 'Set<string>' is not an array type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.` Not sure what that means in the context of my angular-cli project.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about this speciality with typescript. I've updated the answer so that it works with ts @redOctober13

Comment: You're the bomb, thanks! I like the destructuring path too. I'm still learning, but it was easy to add `"downlevelIteration": true` to my tsconfig.json file as well, and then it accepted the destructured version.

Comment: Yeah, I prefer the destructuring too. However there will be many users who don't have added it to tsconfig... @redOctober13... I think it doesn't make much of a difference in the end

Comment: This is still a little harder to read compared to the lodash version which in my mind is more explicit since it uses both `map` and `uniq` and the only other words are variable and property names, whereas this JS-only version has 4 new words and also duplicates 'make.' So I'd prefer to be able to use the lodash version, if I could just get it casted to the right type.

Answer (score 1):

I should have seen this before. The [lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs#chain) for `_.chain()` say:

> Creates a lodash wrapper instance that wraps value with explicit method chain sequences enabled. The result of such sequences must be unwrapped with _#value.

**Thus, this is all that's needed to make it work:**

```
carMakes = _.chain(inventory)
            .map('make')
            .uniq()
            .value()
```

I had tried this before, but VS Code didn't remove the error squiggle *until* I hovered over `value()` weirdly enough, and then the error went away. Since I didn't do that before, I thought it didn't work.